# SAS Enterprise Guide Remove a Project's Program Code Without deleteing the program code

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

How do I remove a program (c:\test.sas) from a project, without deleting that program?

There is no 'close' command - although there is an 'open' command from the File menu. I would like to 'close' the program and remove it from a project.

I am using Enterprise Guide 7.12 using Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit irritating in EG.

You can right click a program in Project tree or project flow window to open context menu.
If you now click on delete, the program will only be removed from project, but the physical file on your harddrive will not be deleted.

If you delete the program in your folder or Server window, it will delete your physical file on harddrive, but not the program in your project, it will be stored in the project file egp.

I added a screenshot from EG 5.1, for 7.1 it is the same...

[image]